# how to set multiple setClassToggle (with multiple classes) to the same trigger ScrollMagic

Tags: javascript, scrollmagic

I have this code:

```js
// init
        var ctrl = new ScrollMagic.Controller();

        var videoArea;
        // return cached value
        function getVideoArea () {
            return videoArea;
        }
        // update value
        function updateVideoArea () {
            videoArea = $(window).height() + $("#start-anim2").height();
        }
        // update on resize
        $(window).on("resize", updateVideoArea);
        // set initial value
        updateVideoArea();

        // create scene
        var scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
            triggerElement: "#start-anim2",
            triggerHook: "onEnter",
            duration: getVideoArea
        })
        .on("enter", function(e) {
            console.log("start");
        })
        .on("leave", function(e) {
            console.log("stop");
        })
        .setClassToggle(".img-app-three:nth-child(2)", "active").addTo(ctrl);
        .setClassToggle(".img-app-three:nth-child(3)", "active").addTo(ctrl);
        .setClassToggle(".img-app-three:nth-child(4)", "active").addTo(ctrl);
```

I would like to add

```js
.setClassToggle(".img-app-three:nth-child(3)", "active").addTo(ctrl);
.setClassToggle(".img-app-three:nth-child(4)", "active").addTo(ctrl);
```

in the same code as shown before, because I want the same trigger but multiple "setClassToggle" on different classes.

How I can do it?

Thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried

`.setClassToggle(".img-app-three:nth-child(3), .img-app-three:nth-child(4)", "active").addTo(ctrl);`

instead of calling the same method over and over again.

Comment: It worked. Thanks. very newbie question, sorry for that.